# how do i repair the program? The program have wrong output

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

We need to fill by number in output.xlsm with values by number with price and quantity from input.xlsm.

We receive in output.xlsm two columns with price, and quantity is missing.
We need input also quantity in E:E column with appropriate values from input.xlsm.

input.xlsm

[image]

output.xlsm

[image]

```
    
Sub Insertdata()
Dim src As Workbook
Dim fnd As Range
Dim d As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Set src = Workbooks.Open("\\s-fa\Prices\Baltopttorg\b.xlsm", True, True)

   ' Set src = Workbooks.Open("E:\Prices\Baltopttorg\baltopttorg_price.xls", True, True)

'    Set src = Workbooks("input.xlsm")
Set Rng = src.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b:b")
d = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Do Until d = lastrow
            Set fnd = Rng.Find(.Cells(d, 2))
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then .Cells(d, 4) = fnd.Offset(, 2)
If Not fnd Is Nothing Then .Cells(d, 5) = fnd.Offset(, 3)
            d = d + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FraW0.png)

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUguu.png)
the script wrongly take fist value and insert in output file
why does it happen?

Comment: You write in both loops the value `fnd.Offset(, 2)` (which is the price in column D). You just need to use `fnd.Offset(, 3)` in the second loop. Which leads to the question why you use two separate loops at all: Just put `.Cells(d, 5) = fnd.Offset(, 3)` to the first loop and get rid of the second loop.

Comment: where do i add   this line .Cells(d, 5) = fnd.Offset(, 3)

Comment: fnd.Offset(, 3) what does it make exactly?

Comment: I thought you know your code. I don't understand why you do a search, but `fnd` is the result cell of that find. The `Offset` returns a cell relative to `fnd`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset. The first parameter is the offset for the row (left empty, so same row), the second is the column offset, so `fnd.Offset(, 3)` is three cells to the left of `fnd`.